# Generic stealthy attacks

Tags: grammaticality

In the following I think I should use "generically". But I am not quite sure. Please confirm

> In this light, we present a formal framework to systematically investigate the feasibility of **generic** stealthy attacks considering

Comment: Are you trying to convey the concept of "anonymous stealthy attacks" or possibly "miscellaneous stealthy attacks"?  What do you mean by generic?

Comment: We don't need to consider the context or semantics. We need to know the syntax only.

Comment: The syntax ***depends on*** the meaning. *"Generic stealthy attacks"* are attacks which are both generic and stealthy. *"Generically stealthy attacks"* are attacks which are stealthy in a generic way.

Comment: Okay. I got it. The answer I was looking for was whether we can use two adjectives back to back without using "and". Generally, adjectives are preceeded by an adverb and some people have a tendency to use adjective instead of adverb (as was done by the original author).

Comment: Because I can't imagine how an attack could be generically stealthy, I think you mean "generic stealthy attacks".

Comment: A better question is, why do you need "generic" at all? Why not just "investigate the feasibility of stealthy attacks"?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what the adjective is meant to describe. Look at it this way:

1. [*Generic*] attacks
2. [*Stealthy*] attacks
3. [*Generically*] attacks
4. [*Generically*] stealthy

If the use of the word in your sentence is meant to describe the "attack" (the noun-form), I'm sure you'll agree that (1) is the correct application of it.